# left job without serving notice period

Tags: job-change, notice-period

I was working for one company for one month. I didn't get any offer letter nor did I submit any documents.

Now I left the job without giving them a notice period.

But they are saying that I should come for 10 days, otherwise they will send notice. But I don't want to go there again.

So if I do not have their offer letter, is it possible for them to send me a notice?

Comment: What do you mean by "send notice"?

Comment: Boss told that he will send me written notice. So is it possible

Comment: Your boss can send you any notice he wants. Hell, *I* could send you a notice. But that means nothing. Maybe it's a translation problem, what bad do you expect to happen after your boss sends you a notice?

Comment: Actually I dont have offer letter. So is it possible to hime to send any kind of notice to me

Comment: You really need to explain your use of "notice". Sorry, but it doesn't translate well. You already quit, so he cannot fire you. Can he send you an angry mail? Sure he can. Please clarify your question. Or maybe add a country tag if your system of notice-periods is so radically different from the one I know.

Comment: @nvoigt18. I just want to know that if I didn't given any notice period and left the job. So is it possible that my boss can send me a notice to work for 10 days of this month. Even I dont have offer letter which means I am not an employee of their organization.

Comment: So what you're asking is "can your boss require you to work 10 more days?" That's a legal question and that's why it's closed. What's odd to me is that he would want you to come back after you quit.  One option is to go back and not do anything. Just sit there. What's he going to do, fire you? You quit without notice so it's not like he'd ever give you a good reference anyway. Regardless @nvoigt is right in his answer below.

Answer (score 6):

There is no country on earth (maybe except North Korea) where you can be *forced* to work. Slavery was abolished a long time ago.

Can your boss send you a piece of paper with whatever text he wants? Yes.

Does that force you to turn up and work? No.

However, there are legal ramifications you should discuss with a legal professional if you are unsure: contracts don't need to be in written form in all countries. In some countries there is a legal notice period that is specified in laws that are used when the notice period is not specified in the contract. If in doubt, ask a local legal expert.

Some advice: your question raises a ton of red flags. You don't have a contract. You did not submit documents. You don't know the legal base of your employment.

Get to know the legal base of your employment. Don't work for shady types without paperwork. Don't just drop out if you don't like it. Get a contract. Keep to the contract.